# Horizontal Mousewheel Scroll conflicts with Map JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am designing a webpage whereby the footer section of the page is to scroll horizontally, using the mouse wheel. There seems to be a conflict between the Esri library and the JQuery script I found to control the horizontal mouse button scrolling. Anybody have any experience with this?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/x8h2j2zf/1/) that shows the functionality

As you will see on that Fiddle, I tried to set the mouse wheel function to look spefically at the "Scrolling" Div, but also added the global "*" as recommended in other threads.

```
$(function() {

   $("Scrolling, *").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {

      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);

      event.preventDefault();

   });

});
```

Comment: Your fiddle links to the Github page for *installing* jquery-mousewheel.  You should link to the source instead:  http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js

Comment: Thanks Rick - I updated the source - the Map does not even load now!  http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/x8h2j2zf/2/  .  Any idea?

Comment: I noticed the same thing.  But this does show a potential conflict.  Perhaps changing the order of the scripts will make a difference.

Comment: I've changed the order of the scripts at the following fiddle, and the map now loads:  http://jsfiddle.net/d0kb3dLj/

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have an error in your jquery selector you forgot to add # before the scrolling ID

It should look like this

```
$("#Scrolling, *")
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was provided by Rick Hitchcock (see comments above).

The order the scripts were included was the issue.  This contains the solution:  [jsfiddle.net/d0kb3dLj](http://jsfiddle.net/d0kb3dLj)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/init.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
```